# Responsive web site with Magnolia

Tags: mobile, webview, responsive-design, magnolia

I want to display some magnolia responsive page in a mobile app through a webview.
In this case I want to hide some section (branding and footer). Is it possible to hide some of these section by passing some parameter to the http url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide some sections, you can configure variation of the template rendering that section for mobile channel and have the template render nothing for mobile channel.

To force mobile channel on desktop you can append *?mgnlChannel=smartphone* to the url.